# OpenCV and Filters Questions

Tags: opencv

I am trying to apply http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html this on an image using OpenCV on android.

The problem is that In that guide they use a 5x5 filter Gaussian. Now I know that you lose pixels (the edge ones if you apply a 3x3, you lose one pixel) if you apply a 5x5 filter you are going to lose 2 right?

OpenCV although seems to keep rendering  them even after the edge detection has been applied. How do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Now I know that you lose pixels, right?*

No, you don't *lose* pixels. 
Usually this is achieved by creating a [border](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#borderinterpolate) around the image before applying the filter.